# Unable to install VS 2013 Ultimate

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2013

I have VS 2010 , 2012 (both ultimate versions) installed on Win7 but unable to install VS 2013 ultimate.Other members in my company have already installed in using same setup.
When I start installation I can only see the splash screen of VS 2013 and then nothing more happens.I have waited till 30-40 mins for any progress but nothing happened.Usually it installs on an average machine with in 30 mins easily. 
I want to know  the issue with installation either using any log which VS installer creates or any other solution?
There are no log entries in Event Viewer as well.

Kindly suggest any solution

Thanks

Comment: You can start the installer with `/log yourfilename.log`. Are you installing from ISO or using the webinstaller?

Comment: tried log flag but still no avail.I tried both ISO and extracted all files as well. following are the last lines of my log which are showing no error.
**[1A48:1B6C][2013-12-10T12:07:14]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
[1A48:1B6C][2013-12-10T12:07:14]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
[1A48:1804][2013-12-10T12:07:14]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed, now create view**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest video drivers for your graphics card. Faulty or outdated video drivers can cause WPF rendering issues with the installer.

You can also try [turning off hardware acceleration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx#disablehardwareacceleration) in the registry. Set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DisableHWAcceleration` to `1`.

[This Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2894215) discusses both of these solutions. While it focuses on problems after installation, the same issues can affect the installer as well.